How to get email address with google id token?
Is there a way to extract the email from the Google ID Token received from the client?
suspend fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse) {
    val credential = result.credential
    val googleIdTokenCredential = 
    GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)
    val googleIdToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
}


{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "temp",
  "aud": "temp",
  "sub": "0000000000000000",
  "nonce": "temp",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/temp",
  "iat": 0000000000,
  "exp": 1729052915
}


There is no email in the body of the id token
https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg
I saw this

The user must be the "sub" (subject). I don't know what this token is!

This is the body of googleIdToken from the handleSignIn function.
